# How to import a variable from another file

Tags: javascript

How can I import a variable of my file called routen.js to my file called main.js.
I tried it with this command: import {a} from '../../routen/routen.js'
But then I got an Error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument."

How can I fix it?

I don't use an export but the variable is set here:

```
    let a = false;
    exports.login = function(request, response){
    var login = request.body.loginname;
    var pwd = request.body.loginpassword;

    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM Benutzer WHERE Benutzername =? AND Passwort =?';
    db.get(sql, login, pwd, (err, row)=>{
   if(row) {
   console.log("Anmeldung erfolgreich.");
   a = true;
   
    }

  else{
    console.log("Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen.");
    a = false;
}

  });
  response.redirect("/");
  response.end();
 };
```

Comment: how do you export it? can you give the code in `routen.js`?

Comment: Oh i don't use an export

Comment: Try to `var {a} = require('../../routen/routen.js');` it instead of `import`ing it. Still, it's juts a guess, because you are not sharing `routen.js`

Comment: Now it says "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require"

Comment: You can't import something that isn't exported.

Comment: How can i export it correctly ?

Comment: you should return the true/false from the function, instead of changing a variable in that file and export that var. On a side note however, DON'T STORE UNHASHED PASSWORDS IN YOUR DATABASE!

Answer (score 0):

In general:

File: `routen.js`

```
let a = false;
exports.a = a;
```

File: `main.js`

```
var a = require("./routen");
console.log(a);
```

`node main.js` shows

```
$ node main.js 
{ a: false }
```

for your case:

```
// file: ./routen.js
exports.login = function (request, response) {
  var login = request.body.loginname;
  var pwd = request.body.loginpassword;

  let sql = "SELECT * FROM Benutzer WHERE Benutzername =? AND Passwort =?";
  db.get(sql, login, pwd, (_err, row) => {
    if (row) {
      console.log("Anmeldung erfolgreich.");
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen.");
      return false;
    }
  });
  response.redirect("/");
  response.end();
};

// file: main.js
var a = require("./routen");
console.log(a.login(req, res)); // should then print false/true
```

Comment: its still saying "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require"

Comment: What are you running that in ? nodejs, browser? Which version? Is it being bundled (webpack, rollup, ...)?

Comment: its version 10.24.0 I am running it on aws

Comment: hm, weird; If it does not complain about import, then try `var login = function (){}...` and then `export default login;` in `routen.js` and then `import login from "./routen.js;"` in `main.js`

Answer (score 0):

I would change `exports.login` to at the end of that file `module.exports = login` in the case login is the function name you are exporting.

to import use the old `var login = require('./routen');`

I am not sure if in version 10 you can destructure on import so better go to the secure.